# Solidity ParserError: Expected ';' but got '{'

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets, mycrypto

having trouble getting past this part, and don't know how to fix this error. Can anyone help or give me advice?

[image]

Comment: Please include the source code as text. That way it will be much easier to try and answer.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to insert ";" at the line above.